# How to make the Speed Calculation being able to calculate from both direction (above to the bottom and from the bottom to the top)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am currently working on a project on human walking speed estimation by using Haar-cascade. The program works as such: the detected object passes two imaginary lines and when it passes the second line the program will show the speed. The currently program that I've worked only calculate the detected object that walks from above to the bottom, but I wanted the program will catch the calculation from below to the top too so it can calculating in both ways.

here's the program:

```
import cv2
import time

cascade_src = 'haarcascade_fullbody.xml'
video_src = 'video-1.mp4'

#line a
ax1=15
ay=225
ax2=600

#line b
bx1=15
by=275
bx2=600

#car num
i = 1
start_time = time.time()

#video ....
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_src)
human_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_src)   

videoWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
videoHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('wisuda-14.mp4', fourcc, 25.0, (videoWidth,videoHeight))

def Speed_Cal(time):
    try:
        Speed = (9.144*3600)/(time*1000)
        return Speed
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print (5)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if (type(img) == type(None)):
        break
    
    #bluring to have exacter detection
    blurred = cv2.blur(img, ksize=(3,3))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    human = human_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.04865, minNeighbors=6)
    
    #line a #i know road has got 
    cv2.line(img,(ax1,ay),(ax2,ay),(255,0,0),2)
    #line b
    cv2.line(img,(bx1,by),(bx2,by),(255,0,0),2)
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in human:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        roi_blurred = blurred[x: x + h, y:y + w]
        roi_gray = gray[x: x + h, y:y + w]
        roi_img = img[x: x + h, y:y + w]
        cv2.circle(img,(int((x+x+w)/2),int((y+y+h)/2)), 2,(0,255,0), -1)
        #cv2.putText(img, "ID : " + str(i), (x, y-15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1);
        
        while int(ay) == int((y+y+h)/2):
            start_time = time.time()
            break
            
        while int(ay) <= int((y+y+h)/2):
            if int(by) <= int((y+y+h)/2)&int(by+10) >= int((y+y+h)/2):
                cv2.line(img, (bx1,by), (bx2,by), (0,255,0), 2)
                Speed = Speed_Cal(time.time() - start_time)
                print("ID Number "+str(i)+" Speed: " + str(int(Speed)))
                i = i + 1
                cv2.putText(img, "Speed: "+str(int(Speed))+"km/jam", (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,0,0), 2);
                break
            else :        
                break
                
                
    out.write(img)
    cv2.imshow('video', img)
    cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
    cv2.imshow('Blurr', blurred)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope you can help guys

Comment: Just use the reference lines in a different order, or take the absolute value of the result?!

Comment: I've been try it but it occur errors everytime people passed the second line.